# Laravel eloquent compare custom value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I'm working on Laravel 5.3 and I have a `where` condition in a `query` like :

`$query = $query->where('city', '=', $city);`

My problem is the variable `$city` I need to compare is a slug version of cities in database, for example if in database I have `Boston Texas` in city, in my variable I have `boston-texas`

How can I compare these values ? Is there a way to dynamically get a slug version in SQL ? With Laravel ?

Comment: It depends on whether you have a mapping table between the slug version and the actual text or you can algorithmically reproduce the slug version out of the normal text.

Comment: Try `str_slug()` helper function. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-slug Also, `where()` method accepts a closure, so you can make the comparison there.

Comment: Something like where(str_slug('city'), '=', $city); ? But with this I slug the word city, not the value